# Wildcard provisioning profiles conflict in Xcode with multiple Apple IDs

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, provisioning-profile

I have several accounts configured in Xcode under Preferences/Accounts and I use Xcode to generate certificates. 

It generated a wildcard provisioning profile for all the accounts I have, with the name `iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *` but I can't find a way to choose which client's wildcard profile do I want to use because I have different certificates for all of them and I'd like to use the appropriate profile with the right account for each client. Now I only see the one that was last updated. 

Does anybody know how to solve this?

If you have some 3rd party plugins or any other tricks/hacks I'd more than love to hear those.

Answer (score 0):

No I don't think you can do anything about this, Its happening to me too, Xcode takes the WildCard ID of the Last updated Account which you add, If you want to use a Specific account to sign your app with you would have to use the developing Profile corresponding to your bundle ID, which are generated by Xcode automatically